# java does not convert from latin to utf8 properly

Tags: java, mysql, utf-8, character-encoding, codepages

I select data from mysql, the database is not in utf8 (the unicode character is save as latin, for example the unicode string `Đỗ Tiến`(correct form) is save as `Äá»— Tiáº¿n`). If I use PHP to echo to html, I just set `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />` the webpage displays correctly.
If I do not set the meta tag, when open by Chrome, the Chrome detect that is in windows-1258 encode, manually change to Unicode (utf-8), the webpage displays correctly.

The problem is: when I select data from mysql using jdbc I convert like this:

```
    byte[] asciiBytes1 = "Äá»— tiáº¿n".getBytes("Cp1258");
    byte[] asciiBytes2 = "Äá»— tiáº¿n".getBytes("ISO-8859-1");
    String unicode1 = new String(asciiBytes1, "UTF-8");
    String unicode2 = new String(asciiBytes2, "UTF-8");
    System.out.println(unicode1);//�?ỗ tiến
    System.out.println(unicode2);//Đ�? tiến
```

as the result, java **does not** convert properly, I try many encodings in http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/intl/encoding.doc.html, not only Cp1258 and ISO-8859-1, but none works.
The 2 simple method to converting is use html file with `Äá»— tiáº¿n` string as I mention before or using notepad++, set encoding ANSI, paste `Äá»— tiáº¿n` string then change to utf-8, it will displays `Đỗ Tiến`(is the correct string I want)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's kinda complicated, it's in modified Windows-1252 where 0x81, 0x8d, 0x8f, 0x90 and 0x9d that are normally
not assigned are replaced with respective C1 characters. It seems Java doesn't take this into account by default
when using Windows-1252.

It is easiest to just fix your database and use UTF-8 everywhere.

Here's the code anyway

```
public static byte[] getBytesModifiedW1252( String str ) {
    final int[] windows1252 = {
            0x0000,0x0001,0x0002,0x0003,0x0004,0x0005,0x0006,0x0007,0x0008,0x0009,0x000A,0x000B,0x000C,0x000D,0x000E,0x000F
            ,0x0010,0x0011,0x0012,0x0013,0x0014,0x0015,0x0016,0x0017,0x0018,0x0019,0x001A,0x001B,0x001C,0x001D,0x001E,0x001F
            ,0x0020,0x0021,0x0022,0x0023,0x0024,0x0025,0x0026,0x0027,0x0028,0x0029,0x002A,0x002B,0x002C,0x002D,0x002E,0x002F
            ,0x0030,0x0031,0x0032,0x0033,0x0034,0x0035,0x0036,0x0037,0x0038,0x0039,0x003A,0x003B,0x003C,0x003D,0x003E,0x003F
            ,0x0040,0x0041,0x0042,0x0043,0x0044,0x0045,0x0046,0x0047,0x0048,0x0049,0x004A,0x004B,0x004C,0x004D,0x004E,0x004F
            ,0x0050,0x0051,0x0052,0x0053,0x0054,0x0055,0x0056,0x0057,0x0058,0x0059,0x005A,0x005B,0x005C,0x005D,0x005E,0x005F
            ,0x0060,0x0061,0x0062,0x0063,0x0064,0x0065,0x0066,0x0067,0x0068,0x0069,0x006A,0x006B,0x006C,0x006D,0x006E,0x006F
            ,0x0070,0x0071,0x0072,0x0073,0x0074,0x0075,0x0076,0x0077,0x0078,0x0079,0x007A,0x007B,0x007C,0x007D,0x007E,0x007F
            ,0x20AC,0x0081,0x201A,0x0192,0x201E,0x2026,0x2020,0x2021,0x02C6,0x2030,0x0160,0x2039,0x0152,0x008D,0x017D,0x008F
            ,0x0090,0x2018,0x2019,0x201C,0x201D,0x2022,0x2013,0x2014,0x02DC,0x2122,0x0161,0x203A,0x0153,0x009D,0x017E,0x0178
            ,0x00A0,0x00A1,0x00A2,0x00A3,0x00A4,0x00A5,0x00A6,0x00A7,0x00A8,0x00A9,0x00AA,0x00AB,0x00AC,0x00AD,0x00AE,0x00AF
            ,0x00B0,0x00B1,0x00B2,0x00B3,0x00B4,0x00B5,0x00B6,0x00B7,0x00B8,0x00B9,0x00BA,0x00BB,0x00BC,0x00BD,0x00BE,0x00BF
            ,0x00C0,0x00C1,0x00C2,0x00C3,0x00C4,0x00C5,0x00C6,0x00C7,0x00C8,0x00C9,0x00CA,0x00CB,0x00CC,0x00CD,0x00CE,0x00CF
            ,0x00D0,0x00D1,0x00D2,0x00D3,0x00D4,0x00D5,0x00D6,0x00D7,0x00D8,0x00D9,0x00DA,0x00DB,0x00DC,0x00DD,0x00DE,0x00DF
            ,0x00E0,0x00E1,0x00E2,0x00E3,0x00E4,0x00E5,0x00E6,0x00E7,0x00E8,0x00E9,0x00EA,0x00EB,0x00EC,0x00ED,0x00EE,0x00EF
            ,0x00F0,0x00F1,0x00F2,0x00F3,0x00F4,0x00F5,0x00F6,0x00F7,0x00F8,0x00F9,0x00FA,0x00FB,0x00FC,0x00FD,0x00FE,0x00FF
        };
    Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

    for( int i = 0; i < windows1252.length; ++i ) {
        map.put( windows1252[i], i);
    }
    byte replacement = (byte)0x003F;

    byte[] ret = new byte[str.length()];

    for( int i = 0; i < str.length(); ++i ) {
        int cp = str.charAt(i);
        Integer w1252 = map.get(cp);
        ret[i] = w1252 == null ? replacement : (byte)(int)w1252;
    }

    return ret;
}

public static void main(String args[]) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    byte[] bytes = getBytesModifiedW1252( "Äá»— tiáº¿n" );
    System.out.println(new String(bytes, "UTF-8"));
    //Đỗ tiến
}
```

Here's the opposite:

```
public static String getStringModifiedW1252( byte[] bytes ) {

    final int[] windows1252 = {
            0x0000,0x0001,0x0002,0x0003,0x0004,0x0005,0x0006,0x0007,0x0008,0x0009,0x000A,0x000B,0x000C,0x000D,0x000E,0x000F
            ,0x0010,0x0011,0x0012,0x0013,0x0014,0x0015,0x0016,0x0017,0x0018,0x0019,0x001A,0x001B,0x001C,0x001D,0x001E,0x001F
            ,0x0020,0x0021,0x0022,0x0023,0x0024,0x0025,0x0026,0x0027,0x0028,0x0029,0x002A,0x002B,0x002C,0x002D,0x002E,0x002F
            ,0x0030,0x0031,0x0032,0x0033,0x0034,0x0035,0x0036,0x0037,0x0038,0x0039,0x003A,0x003B,0x003C,0x003D,0x003E,0x003F
            ,0x0040,0x0041,0x0042,0x0043,0x0044,0x0045,0x0046,0x0047,0x0048,0x0049,0x004A,0x004B,0x004C,0x004D,0x004E,0x004F
            ,0x0050,0x0051,0x0052,0x0053,0x0054,0x0055,0x0056,0x0057,0x0058,0x0059,0x005A,0x005B,0x005C,0x005D,0x005E,0x005F
            ,0x0060,0x0061,0x0062,0x0063,0x0064,0x0065,0x0066,0x0067,0x0068,0x0069,0x006A,0x006B,0x006C,0x006D,0x006E,0x006F
            ,0x0070,0x0071,0x0072,0x0073,0x0074,0x0075,0x0076,0x0077,0x0078,0x0079,0x007A,0x007B,0x007C,0x007D,0x007E,0x007F
            ,0x20AC,0x0081,0x201A,0x0192,0x201E,0x2026,0x2020,0x2021,0x02C6,0x2030,0x0160,0x2039,0x0152,0x008D,0x017D,0x008F
            ,0x0090,0x2018,0x2019,0x201C,0x201D,0x2022,0x2013,0x2014,0x02DC,0x2122,0x0161,0x203A,0x0153,0x009D,0x017E,0x0178
            ,0x00A0,0x00A1,0x00A2,0x00A3,0x00A4,0x00A5,0x00A6,0x00A7,0x00A8,0x00A9,0x00AA,0x00AB,0x00AC,0x00AD,0x00AE,0x00AF
            ,0x00B0,0x00B1,0x00B2,0x00B3,0x00B4,0x00B5,0x00B6,0x00B7,0x00B8,0x00B9,0x00BA,0x00BB,0x00BC,0x00BD,0x00BE,0x00BF
            ,0x00C0,0x00C1,0x00C2,0x00C3,0x00C4,0x00C5,0x00C6,0x00C7,0x00C8,0x00C9,0x00CA,0x00CB,0x00CC,0x00CD,0x00CE,0x00CF
            ,0x00D0,0x00D1,0x00D2,0x00D3,0x00D4,0x00D5,0x00D6,0x00D7,0x00D8,0x00D9,0x00DA,0x00DB,0x00DC,0x00DD,0x00DE,0x00DF
            ,0x00E0,0x00E1,0x00E2,0x00E3,0x00E4,0x00E5,0x00E6,0x00E7,0x00E8,0x00E9,0x00EA,0x00EB,0x00EC,0x00ED,0x00EE,0x00EF
            ,0x00F0,0x00F1,0x00F2,0x00F3,0x00F4,0x00F5,0x00F6,0x00F7,0x00F8,0x00F9,0x00FA,0x00FB,0x00FC,0x00FD,0x00FE,0x00FF
        };

    StringBuilder ret = new StringBuilder(bytes.length);

    for( int i = 0; i < bytes.length; ++i ) {
        ret.append( (char) windows1252[(bytes[i] < 0 ? 256 + bytes[i] : bytes[i] )] );
    }

    return ret.toString();

}

public static void main(String args[]) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    String str = "Đỗ tiến";
    String w1252 = getStringModifiedW1252( str.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    System.out.println(w1252);
    //Äá»— tiáº¿n
}
```

You probably want to stash the map and array somewhere instead of creating them when the methods are called

Comment: I can not edit database because it isn't under my permission
but is there any way that does not using java-processing, example convert by sql command?

Comment: @yelliver Well you can try `"jdbc:mysql://hostName/dbName?characterEncoding=UTF-8"` in the jbdc connection string

Comment: it does work because my database is not in utf8 format (I have noticed)
I am satisfied with your solution now
And can you please provide me the reverse solution for query LIKE in sql (convert from utf8 string to modified windows1252 string)?

Comment: @yelliver You mean how to convert `"Đỗ tiến"` to `"Äá»— tiáº¿n"`?

Comment: yes, I do not understand all your code but I think it find some of value and replace with 0x003F, but it is n to 1 so I can not do reversely

Comment: @yelliver well I have added the code for reverse operation, hope it helps

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
byte[] asciiBytes1 = "Äá»— tiáº¿n".getBytes("Cp1258");
byte[] asciiBytes2 = "Äá»— tiáº¿n".getBytes("ISO-8859-1");
String unicode1 = new String(asciiBytes1, "Cp1258");
String unicode2 = new String(asciiBytes2, "ISO-8859-1");
System.out.println(unicode1);//�?ỗ tiến
System.out.println(unicode2);//Đ�? tiến
```